# Having a connecting to kernel issue in a python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed jupyter using anaconada and whenever I make a python notebook I get a connecting to kernel message next to the trusted message (sorry I couldn't add an image) I then tried reloading the site and got a 'this site can't be reached' error

Comment: An image would probably help figure out what's up, what was the issue with adding one?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install only the jupyter notebook by the following steps:

1: ->> Open *'Run'* type **cmd** and press ok.

*Run the commands given below:*

2: ->> **pip uninstall jupyter notebook.**

3: ->> **pip install jupyter notebook.**

4: ->> Now to open in browser simple type->>**jupyter notebook**

Now to open it in future just follow **step 1** & **step 4.**